# Determining factors for number of tasks for hive on spark with dynamic allocation enabled

Tags: performance, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

We have a number of queries using hive on spark with dynamic allocation enabled running in different environments with the same configuration .

The number of cores and memory is different for different environment. On checking further, number of tasks in stage is also varying. The strange thing is that the number of tasks for a table with lesser number of records with the same filter criteria is more than the number of tasks for the same query with more records in different environment.

On checking the environment tab the properties are exactly similar.

Is there any way to determine the factors which determine the number of tasks and the reason of it being more for the same filter criteria for table with lesser number of records.